# Select en deselect multiple items from array #Processing

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, processing

**What is happening now?**

At this moment I am able to click on a block, receive its number, and store the numbers to `int[] vakkenSelected`. The maximum ammount of numbers stored in `int[] vakkenSelected`is 3. That means I can select only 3 blocks (`selCount < 3`). Each time a block is pressed selCount increases by 1. selCount is used to store the number in the next key from `int[] vakkenSelected`.

**What do I want to happen?**

- The same block can't be selected more then once.
- If pressed again on a block that is already selected (stored in
  `int[] vakkenSelected`) it must be deselected (removed from `int[] vakkenSelected` or changed to '-1').

Thanks.

Outside scope:

```java
int selCount = 0;
int[] vakkenSelected = new int[3];
```

Inside scope:

```java
void mousePressed() {
  int x = mouseX;
  int y = mouseY;
  for(int i = 0; i < posities.length; i++) {
    int num = posities[i][0]; 
    int posX = posities[i][1]; 
    int posY = posities[i][2]; 
    if(x > posX && x < posX+vakBreedte && y > posY && y < posY+vakHoogte && selCount < 3) {  
      vakkenSelected[selCount] = num; 
      selCount++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] instead of a disconnected snippet. Can you be more clear about what you want to happen vs what's actually happening? When you say the max selections is 3, does that mean you can only select a total of 3 blocks? Or does that mean each block can be selected 3 times?

Comment: This is minimal and complete right? And yes by max selections I mean you can only select a total of 3 blocks. I'll try to update my post and be more specific.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: @ThomasBeumer that is not javascript.

Comment: Processing is a form of Javascript my friend

Comment: @ThomasBeumer no its not my friend, but anyway. You need to iterate over the `vakkenSelected` array to see if the `num` is already in there. If it is not then do the `vakkenSelected[selCount] = num` otherwise remove it and compact the array (see https://www.processing.org/discourse/beta/num_1118112730.html)

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. But I'll try to help in a general sense.

It sounds like you already know what you need to do:

> The same block can't be selected more then once.
>
> If pressed again on a block that is already selected (stored in int[] vakkenSelected) it must be deselected (removed from int[] vakkenSelected or changed to '-1').

I recommend you run through [this process](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) of turning requirements into code.

It sounds like you could use a 2D boolean array, and just check whether that block is already active. If it is, switch it to inactive, and add or remove it from the selected list.